# jquery two loops with timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm work on script that will send ajax post to another page, i need to make two for loops before send ajax request with time out, one of them send successcfully but when make another loop it send all requests same time and make the server down:

```
     $("#me").on("click", function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();

       var lines = $('#emails').val().split('\n');


       var sendToServer = function(lines, index){
       item = lines[index];
       if (item.trim().length != 0){

         for(idd = 1; idd <= 100; idd++){  
         $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: 'inc/save.php',
           data: { users : lines[index] , id : idd  },
           success: function(msg){
                $('#result').append(msg);


             if (index < lines.length) {
               setTimeout(
                 function () { sendToServer(lines, index+1); },
                 5000 // delay in ms
               );
             }
           }


         });

         }

       }
       else { sendToServer(lines, index+1); }
    };

    sendToServer(lines, 0);




            });
```

Comment: I guess the server doesn't like 100 requests all at once?

Comment: it's sample here ( 100 )  the final code will have 1000 request, and for sure server can't process 1000 request at same time so i need to process it one by one with timeout between each one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will delay a specified amount of time between every request

```
$("#me").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var lines = $('#emails').val().split('\n');
    var requestDelay = 5000;
    var sendToServer = function (index) {
        item = lines[index];
        if (item.trim().length != 0) {
            var max = 100;
            var sendOne = function (idd) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'inc/save.php',
                    data: {
                        users: lines[index],
                        id: idd
                    },
                    success: function (msg) {
                        $('#result').append(msg);
                        if (idd <= max) {
                            setTimeout(sendOne, requestDelay, idd + 1);
                        } else {
                            if (index < lines.length) {
                                setTimeout(sendToServer, requestDelay, index + 1);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            };
            sendOne(1);
        }
    };
    sendToServer(0);
});
```

It's set to 5000 `requestDelay` - but you could probably reduce that significantly

A "modern" code version using async/await and the fact that jquery.ajax returns a *thenable*

```
$("#me").on("click", async function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const requestDelay = 5000;
    const wait = result => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, requestDelay, result));

    const getIdd = async users => {
        for ( let id = 1; id <= 100; ++id) {
            const msg = await $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'inc/save.php',
                data: { users, id }
            });
            $('#result').append(msg);
            await wait();
        }
    };
    const lines = $('#emails').val().split('\n');
    for (let line of lines) {
        await getIdd(lines);
    }
});
```

Comment: @MohamedAldanaf - I was interrupted (real life gets in the way :p), was going to post a "modern" code version that's very neat and tidy - I can add it if you wish

Comment: I would be grateful to you if you do :)